# Parse.com Class Level Permissions: No longer supporting operation specific permissions?

Tags: parse-platform, clp

In the [Parse.com Docs](https://parse.com/docs/data) it clearly shows that you can edit Class Level Permissions for specific operations, Read: Get, Find; Write: Update, Create, Delete; etc.

However, when viewing the Data Browser, I am only seeing the option to allow for "Read" or "Write", see below:

[image: Current Data Browser]

Am I misunderstanding the documentation or is it out of date?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that they've added a "Simple" and "Advanced View". On the top right of the "Security" dialog there is a cogwheel, which reveals the "Advanced" slider:

[image: Advanced CLP]